# Installing Ubuntu with Fake Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, windows-7, dell

I'd really like to install Ubuntu on my computer (Dell Inspiron 1525) but I can't get the LiveCD or the installation to work.

This computer was gifted to me and it has a fake Windows 7 operating system. At least it says the the copy of Windows is not genuine.

I've successfully burned the .iso to a DVD disc. What next?

Comment: "can't get the LiveCD or the installation to work" doesn't give us much to work with: what did you try exactly, and what happened? Are you able to enter the computer's BIOS and set the boot order?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you few steps to install Ubuntu

1. Configure your BIOS to boot on CD
2. Boot on CD
3. Follow the instructions, but be careful with partionning, especially if you want to keep your Windows configuration : defrag first your Windows partition and then cut your partition with partition manage, then click on dualboot.
   If you don't want to keep your Windows, simply click on erase Windows